# Onomatopoeia/interjection for snatching something?

Tags: onomatopoeia

E.g. "the dog went [?snatch?] and away it ran with the Frisbee". The word indicates a [sudden and unexpected move](http://translate.google.com/translate?sl=ro&tl=en&js=n&prev=_t&hl=en&ie=UTF-8&u=http%3A%2F%2Fdexonline.ro%2Fdefinitie%2Fha%25C5%25A3) made to catch or grab something.

Comment: I've heard "yoink" for taking something away quickly...

Answer (score 2):

This comes to mind:

[*"Yoink"*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/yoink) (+[urban dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=yoink)) - a word that has a similar meaning to "to steal", can be used as a verb. I think it is usually used when referring to some small object.

> Though I cherished my automobile, I had to purchase a new one when my second cousin came up from behind me and politely exclaimed, "Yoink" while taking my car keys.
>
> Yoink, I stole the cookies!
>
> I wanted his CD player, so I yoinked it.

Comment: That's what immediately came to mind - even though when you snatch something it doesn't really make a sound. Though I think I've also seen *snatched!* in a comic before